# How do I perform periodic background work in API >= 26, even when the app is closed?

Tags: android, notifications, android-alarms

I'm trying to perform a task (for the purpose of this question, write a line to a log file) every half hour, even when my app is closed. This is proving near-impossible (in API version 28 at least). How should it be done?

I've tried:

- WorkManager to schedule periodic jobs
- WorkManager to schedule one-off jobs (and then manually rescheduling)
- AlarmManager's setExactAndAllowWhileIdle calling directly into an IntentService
- AlarmManager's setExactAndAllowWhileIdle calling a method on an IntentService via a BroadcastReceiver.

All work fine while the app is running. As soon as the app stops, the callbacks stop.

I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S8. Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: are you sure that WorkManager doesnt work for you? I use work manager with periodic work and it works

Comment: Have you looked at JobService ?https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService